# How to set the right timezone in Laravel 4 ?

Tags: laravel-4, timezone

I went to `config/local/app.php`

What should I change this `'timezone' => 'UTC'` to ?

If I want to set it for Eastern Time US.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EST is UTC-5. Intuitively you'd think you want to change it to UTC-5. So:

`'timezone' => 'UTC-5'`

However this might give you an error. If UTC-5 does not work, try:

`'timezone' => 'America/New_York'`

(or if you like things further north, `'America/Toronto'`)

See: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est

Comment: I did according to your suggestion. I got this [error message](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqlfl7auxt3qqv0/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Ah, perhaps it wants 'America/New_York'. Try that.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: It went through, no error message, but show wrong time. :( . See [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8b69wdv6oyq8d2/wrong-time.JPG?dl=0). It should show as 9:57 AM because that's when I posted it.

Comment: I suspect that, my database grabbing the wrong TIME, that's why it showing the wrong time. Is there another setting for the timezone for the database ? I used phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Is that a record from a database? It might need to be re-populated if it was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67142/discussion-between-iggy-and-mephoros).